# Batch script error with loop over range of values

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am writing a Windows batch script to loop over a range of numbers. When I save the below script in a .bat file and run, I get the following error: `%param was unexpected at this time`.

Script:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /L %%param IN (1,1,10) DO ECHO %%param
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Open up a Command Prompt window and enter `for /?` you'll clearly see what the issue is when you see that all metavariables have single characters. `@(For /L %%I In (1,1,10)Do @Echo %%I)&Pause`

Comment: `FOR` Loops only allow single character variables created in the loop.  `%P` at the CLI or `%%P` in a batch script.  he Variable chosen is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FOR` Loops only allow single character variables created in the loop.  `%P` at the CLI or `%%P` in a batch script.  he Variable chosen is case sensitive.

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /L %%P IN (1,1,10) DO (
  ECHO=%%P
)
```